# How to block outbound traffic in CentOS without using IPTables or Firewalld?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, iptables, firewalld

I am trying to implement something like Chaos engineering, so implementing the functionalities manually. One of the functionality is blocking outbound DNS traffic without using IPTables or firewalld.

I am kind of completely out of ideas here, my needs are below

- No IPTables or firewall
- I should be able to mention the type of protocol ( TCP/ UDP )
- And Port Number

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways "without using IPTables or firewalld". I also handled IPv6 when easily possible.

- [Traffic Control](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html): [`tc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html): probably any version of CentOS even EOL ones

  Requires to know the outbound interface name (and thus how routing is done in advance). Let's say the interface that will be used for outgoing traffic is named `eth0`. You can use the `tc` command to add a [filter](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/components.html#c-filter) on an interface. Filters can be added only on classful disciplines, so a "dummy" classful qdisc whose own properties won't be really used here is added for this purpose: *prio*.

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: pref 1 protocol ip basic match '
      (cmp (u8 at 9 layer network eq 6) or cmp (u8 at 9 layer network eq 17)) and
          cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 53)' action drop
  '
  tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: pref 2 protocol ipv6 basic match '
      (cmp (u8 at 6 layer network eq 6) or cmp (u8 at 6 layer network eq 17)) and
          cmp(u16 at 2 layer transport eq 53)' action drop
  '
  ```

  notes:

  - *u8 at 9 layer network* for IPv4 is the Protocol field in the [IPv4 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header): its value is compared to 6 for *tcp* or 17 for *udp*.
  - *u8 at 6 layer network* for IPv6 is the almost but not equivalent Next header field in the [IPv6 fixed header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header). This is not catching all cases: if there are [Extension headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) between the Fixed header and the Payload Header, then IPv6's fixed header's Next header which is used above won't match the payload protocol (6 for *tcp* or 17 for *udp*). As there could be multiple numbers of linked extension headers, *tc* isn't well suited for this unless it gets a built-in support in some module.
  - *u16 at 2 layer transport* above is the destination port, for [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) [protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure).

  This won't be caught by a local application.
- [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page): `nft`. CentOS 7 or 8

  Even CentOS 7's 3.10 kernel got a backported version of *nftables*. Just add the equivalent of *iptables* with *nftables*. An *inet* family table handles simultaneously IPv4 and IPv6.

  ```
  nft add table inet t
  nft add chain inet t output '{ type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept; }'
  nft add rule inet t output udp dport 53 drop
  nft add rule inet t output tcp dport 53 drop
  ```

  It's unclear if a local application will catch an error because of these rules.

  Will also affect local connections from local system to itself unless an exception is added.
- policy routing: [`ip rule`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html). CentOS 8 only because this [requires kernel >= 4.17](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.17#Networking)

  Newer kernels can also use ports to match routing rules. So just have rules that drop anything to udp port 53 and tcp port 53 instead of routing it.

  ```
  ip rule add ipproto udp dport 53 blackhole
  ip rule add ipproto tcp dport 53 blackhole
  ip -6 rule add ipproto udp dport 53 blackhole
  ip -6 rule add ipproto udp dport 53 blackhole
  ```

  This will be caught by a local application with EINVAL (as described in ... [`ip route(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-route.8.html#DESCRIPTION)). Changing the type of network "outage" might alter the error and thus the behavior (eg: from *blackhole* to *prohibit*).

  Won't affect local connections from system to itself (whose local route evaluation happens before, at precedence 0).

Comment: Just adding as reference https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/